# Amazon Kindle Fire Music playlist

Tags: android, playlist, kindle

I'm trying to get my app to play a playlist created on the device.
On non amazon devices i used

```
String[] proj ={"_id", "playlist_name" };

Uri gMusicUri = Uri.parse("content://com.google.android.music.MusicContent/playlists");

Cursor cursor = m_mainActivity.getContentResolver().query(gMusicUri,  proj , null, null, null);
```

To get my playlist, but on Amazon devices there isn't a google music app, so what's the amazon equivalent content uri for playlists?

Comment: I tried using MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI but that always returns an empty cursor on devices using google music player and on the amazon kindle fire